# The 'Rate Controlled' connection 'appm' access to protected services is denied

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

We are now deploying our application to production. But an issue of Rate Controlled show up? How can we solve this one? Any steps might solve this issue.The issue is connecting to *** using a adapter that uses a java.
We are getting the error from ipad device.

```
 <Warning>: DEBUG: Submitting credentials to Worklight
 <Warning>: DEBUG: Checking for authRequired attribute in responseJSON
 <Warning>: DEBUG: authRequired attribute is present in responseJSON true
 <Warning>: DEBUG: authrequired === true? true
 <Warning>: DEBUG: authRequired is true, calling onShowLogin
 <Warning>: DEBUG: do login [object Object]
 <Error>: HID: The 'Rate Controlled' connection 'appme' access to protected services is denied.
 <Warning>: void SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation *): delegate (webView:runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage:initiatedByFrame:) failed to return after waiting 10 seconds. main run loop mode: kCFRunLoopDefaultMode
 <Warning>: ERROR: Failed to submit credentials to worklight
```

We are fetching credentials to ***. The adapter use jars and java classes to access the credentials.

Comment: Can you provide the actual, full, error message you're getting? Where do you get this error - server or client? When do you get this error? What is your implementation like? What are you doing in your adapter?

Answer (score 0):

Does not appear to be MobileFirst Platform-related.

Read through these threads, as it looks like you have some native code written by you here that is involved:

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6074570
http://forums.coronalabs.com/topic/47830-hid-the-passive-connection-appname-access-to-protected-services-is-denied/

From these threads it seems that the real issue not the "HID ... access denied", but something else in your  code that affects the network requests.

Note that you are also printing "[object object]"...

If this is working in the development environment but not in your production environment, then indeed you need to verify your network for anything potential who may cause delays or block requests.